# alignment equally after a particular symbol

Tags: align

I want to list something like this but all : symbols should be at same horizontal space like the all other items in the list

A          : jkajdkpajd

Bnk     : odoida

kaak ka: asjad

How to achieve this in latex? other than table?

Comment: You could place each leading item in a left-aligned `\makebox` of fixed width, followed by the colon.  You could also use a `tabbing` environment or, as you note, a `tabular` environment (which does not need to be inside of a `table`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here I show three ways: `\makebox`, `tabbing`, and `tabular`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\parindent 0in
\begin{document}
RAW: \par
A : jkajdkpajd\par
Bnk : odoida\par
kaak ka: asjad

\bigskip
\newlength\longest
\setbox0=\hbox{kaak ka}
\setlength\longest{\wd0}
MAKEBOX:\par
\makebox[\longest][l]{A}: jkajdkpajd\par
\makebox[\longest][l]{Bnk}: odoida\par
\makebox[\longest][l]{kaak ka}: asjad

\bigskip
TABBING:
\begin{tabbing}
kaak ka\=\kill
A \>: jkajdkpajd\\
Bnk \>: odoida\\
kaak ka\>: asjad
\end{tabbing}

\bigskip
TABULAR:\par
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}l}
A &: jkajdkpajd\\
Bnk &: odoida\\
kaak ka&: asjad
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

With `enumitem`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}[align=left,labelwidth=\widthof{kaak ka}]
\item[A]: jkajdkpajd\par
\item[Bnk]: odoida\par
\item[kaak ka]: asjad
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]